# CPU and system Fans won't stop in Suspend Mode in Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: 14.04, uefi, suspend, 15.10, fan

Installed Ubuntu 15.10 in UEFI on new Asus built PC with skylake processor. Ubuntu 15.10 is the sole OS on this machine.

Intel inbuilt HD graphics with NO external Graphics Card.

Now when I suspend/sleep the system, the led lit system fans and CPU fans keep running, making me feel that suspend is not working.

Is this normal with Ubuntu ( i am new to ubuntu)? If not what could be the reason and solution? Please help.